# SEO for an online text-based game

Tags: seo, dynamic-data

I'm building an **online text-based game** much like Mafia Wars. I'm using PHP on a Mysql database.

My website will consist of a **layout** which will hold most on the navigation links and game controls while most of the pages will be called via **Ajax** calls.
I don't want the page to reload completely to give the user a feel of a desktop game.

Now that means that there will be **only one** real page with various dynamic content.

From a **SEO** point of view is this good or not ? I mean I will only have one 2 meta tags in my layout and  won't be able to put in meta tags in the Ajax called view.
Will the search engine spider be able to index my Ajax called view also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, search engines do not crawl content generated by JavaScript or Ajax. The most notable exception being Google's crawlable Ajax. But that only applies to Google and even then that's [a bad idea.](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs)

To make your game more search engine friendly you will need to make content available via static links. Without these you essentially have a one page website which is very difficult to rank well. **But** it *can* if you obtain enough incoming links which is possible if your game is very good.

Comment: By "content available via static links" do you mean that I need other sites referring to my website (i.e. Other websites pointing to my game)?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better question for the [Webmasters site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but if you provide both AJAX and non-AJAX views on your site, then you don't have to worry about whether or not the search engine can see the content. Plain HTML versions should provide index-able text for the search engines.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean exactly by "Plain HTML versions" ?

Comment: I mean, instead of pages generated through an AJAX call, if you want your content to be indexed by non-javascript enabled crawlers, you need to provide a way for them to access the content without using JavaScript. See `John Conde's` answer for a little more detail.